# how to restore binary data from database sql server back to file(attachment not image) VB.net Desktop

Tags: vb.net, file, binary

i have successfully inserted(after convert) a file that i uploaded to database server in binary data type, the problem is i don't know how to restore(convert back) binary data to a file?

i have searched on google but i just found converting image to binary and binary to image

```
    Dim ms As New IO.MemoryStream(rs.Fields("image field").Value)
show the picture in the picturebox
picturebox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

and it didn't solve my problem i want convert binary to any file that i uploaded before not image file??

could someone help me out of this problem
thanks i really appreciate

Comment: Is not very clear what you are asking. Please provide code or explanation of what you did to convert the file ? from which format or extension did you convert the file ? if is just a stream of bytes then you just need to read them and store them

Comment: Usually it is just a matter of reversing whatever you did to store it as binary